# Serialize public properties using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, wcf, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) implementation to serialize/deserialize .NET objects to JS and vice versa, all works fine until running `GetWCFData()` in the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public class WebLookup
    {
        WCFService.WCFServiceClient svc;
        IsoDateTimeConverter DateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();


        List<WCFContract.Language> Languages { get; set; }
        List<WCFContract.Group> Groups { get; set; }
        List<WCFContract.User> Users { get; set; }

        public WebLookup()
        {
            DateConverter.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            DateConverter.DateTimeStyles = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal;
        }

        public string GetWCFData()
        {
            svc = new WCFService.WCFServiceClient();
            WebLookup weblookup = new WebLookup();
            weblookup.Languages = svc.GetWCFLanguages().ToList();
            weblookup.Groups = svc.GetWCFGroups().ToList();
            weblookup.Users = svc.GetWCFUsers().ToList();

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weblookup, DateConverter);
        } 

    }
```

Members `Languages`, `Groups`, and `Users` get populated successfully when calling the WCF service but
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lookup, DateConverter)` always returns an empty JSON string to the client (web browser), this is strange as it usually works fine for me in other areas, the only difference is that here I have the populated `WebLookup` members declared as public properties in the class itself.

Comment: Any reason for not using the built-in `JavaScriptSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer`?

Comment: What's the error that you receive?

Comment: I have actually just replaced the serialization line with: return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(weblookup) to see if its any different but got the same result, an empty string.

Comment: @Bojan-Skrchevski No errors, just an empty string, despite weblookup having its Languages, Groups, and Users populated with values.

Comment: @Maya - also I don't see serialization attributes in WebLookup class. Do you include: [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.[option])] ???

Comment: Ok, I tried adding [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)] then [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)] to the top of the class but that unfortunately still does not work, same result (string returned is "{}" )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Languages, Groups and Users properties need to be declared as Public members in order to be Serialised by either JSON.NET or the built-in JavaScriptSerializer, this is not the case in your code.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, data is serialized correctly now, thank you!

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct.  Add the attribute [JsonProperty] attribute to the property and it will be serialized.

Comment: @Nuzzolilo No, that answer is correct, it did the job for me, adding [JsonProperty] didn't work, in fact this property only existed in JSON.NET 4.5